# Cors blocking HTTP delete Method

Tags: java, angular, frontend, backend, http-delete

I am getting a CORS error when I try to use my HTTP Delete method.
My Frontend is Angular-ionic and my Server is a Java server. Both are self-made.

I tried to disable CORS in the Browser, by doing so I managed the Request to work and the Error to disappear. Although that's fine, my goal is to make it work every time for EVERY user.

Here is my Code with a bit of Background:

```
      console.log('User Management Service Delete User()');
      const myParams = new HttpParams().set('id', this.cookieService.get('AccessToken'));
      console.log(myParams);
      return this.http.delete(this.endpoint + 'users/delete', { params: myParams});
    }
```

The code above is my FRONTEND (clientside) code. I am simply trying to delete a user.

```
    public int serveUserDelete(HTTPServer.Request req, HTTPServer.Response resp) throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> params = req.getParams();
        String response;
        String paramvalue;
        String  accessToken;    
        
        resp.getHeaders().add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        resp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        resp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        resp.getHeaders().add("id", "*");
        resp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, DELETE, POST, GET, PATCH, PUT");
        
        response = "";
        //Id aus dem Parameter auslesen
        if (params.containsKey("id")) {
            //es gibt einen Parameter id. Suche den Wertd dazu
            accessToken = params.get("id");
            System.out.println(accessToken);
            
        } else {
            accessToken = null;
        }
        response = um.userDelete(accessToken);
        resp.send(200, response);
        return 0;
    }
```

The Code above now, is my Java server.
The headers were added cause of trial and error.

Here the error I am getting:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/umyServerUrl/users/delete?id=u@Yy0NZPLx%266HxYNF%23tv' 
from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

threw testing (with disabled browser cors etc.) I found out that the methods on my server work just fine.

Here you can see my "PARAMS" and the Observable of my delete Request printed in the Console:

```
HttpParams 
{updates: Array(1), 
cloneFrom: HttpParams, 
encoder: HttpUrlEncodingCodec, 
map: null}
cloneFrom: 
nullencoder: 
HttpUrlEncodingCodec {}[[Prototype]]:
Objectconstructor: class
HttpUrlEncodingCodecdecodeKey: ƒ 
decodeKey(key)decodeValue: ƒ 
decodeValue(value)encodeKey: ƒ 
encodeKey(key)encodeValue: ƒ 
encodeValue(value)[[Prototype]]: 
Objectmap: 
Map(1)[[Entries]]0: {"id" => Array(1)}
key: "id" value: ['hTxYusBwuB7pbUUCkW9E']size: 1[[Prototype]]:
Mapupdates: null[[Prototype]]: 
Object
user-management.service.ts:35 

**Oberservabel:**

Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, 
operator: MapOperator}
operator: MapOperator
project: res => res.body
length: 1
name: ""
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
[[FunctionLocation]]: http.mjs:1300
[[Prototype]]: ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[2]
thisArg: undefined
[[Prototype]]: Object
call: ƒ call(subscriber, source)
constructor: class MapOperator
[[Prototype]]: Object
source: Observable
operator: FilterOperator {thisArg: undefined, predicate: ƒ}
source: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MergeMapOperator}
_isScalar: false
[[Prototype]]: Object
_isScalar: false
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This combination of Access-Control headers is invalid.

```java
        resp.getHeaders().add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        resp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        resp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

You cannot set [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to `*` and also allow [`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials).

> For requests **without credentials**, the literal value "*" can be specified as a wildcard; the value tells browsers to allow requesting code from any origin to access the resource. Attempting to use the wildcard with credentials results in an error.

This might be a large scale issue of the system architecture.
For now you could test setting the *Allow-Origin* header like this:

```java
        resp.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8100");
```

However if it's supposed to work from an arbitrary number of clients another architecture might be necessary.

CORS is a security feature. Do not "trial and error" around with security features!

Comment: Hey, I am sending an ID which is my AccessToken. I am sending it to the Server, which it uses to find the user it has to delete. 

Also the Headers somehow fixed the same Problem when I used them on my POST requests. (I got them from my teacher).

Does this explain the request a bit better?

Comment: The error helps a little. You're still developing on your local machine. CORS and _localhost_ addresses can be a pain. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Interesstingly enought I had a similar error in my get function, and by adding your header it works there now. The other function is still not fully functional though. Funny enought both (delete and get requests) are almost identical in the fronend part. The error still exists in the Delete Method tho

Comment: Well it's hard to help without an example request. Please provide an example HTTP request of the client. Does it contain an `Origin` header?

Comment: I am not sure how I can display my exact request so I just tried my best. I displayed the Observable and my Params. I dont think there are any headers tbh since I am not adding any. I Edited the inital post! (I do not think that it contains an origin header if you know a way I could surly check (using angular-ionic) than lemme know I will try it)

Comment: This is quiet the complex topic as it's not just about your application and CORS, but also about how the Browser handles the requests. It's most likely easier to test it without localhost. If you want to get a representation of the request you could do the following steps:
1. Open the page previous to the DELETE
2. Open the dev tools of your browser
2.1 go to the network tab
2.2 filter for `users/delete`
3. send the delete request
4. right click on the listed request 
There should be options like _copy > Copy as cURL (bash)_ or similar.
5. Paste the command in here.